# How to take a word from a dictionary by its definition

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a code where I need to take a string of words, convert it into numbers where `hi bye hi hello` would turn into `0 1 0 2`.  I have used dictionary's to do this and this is why I am having trouble on the next part. I then need to compress this into a text file, to then decompress and reconstruct it into a string again.  This is the bit I am stumped on.

The way I would like to do it is by compressing the indexes of the numbers, so the `0 1 0 2` bit into the text file with the dictionary contents, so in the text file it would have `0 1 0 2` and `{hi:0, bye:1, hello:3}`.

Now what I would like to do to decompress or read this into the python file, to use the *indexes*(this is how I will refer to the `0 1 0 2` from now on) to then take each word out of the dictionary and reconstruct the sentence, so if a **0** came up, it would look into the dictionary and then find what has a `0` definition, then pull that out to put into the string, so it would find `hi` and take that.

I hope that this is understandable and that at least one person knows how to do it, because I am sure it is possible, however I have been unable to find anything here or on the internet mentioning this subject.

Comment: What do you mean by compress this into text file? Are you talking about saving the dictionary in a text file?

Comment: yes I need to write the dictionary and the index list of the sentence into the text file

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Especially **well-defined** sample input / output would be helpful. _write the dictionary and the index list of the sentence into the text file_ may be done in multiple ways, so that problem statement is fairly ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TheLazyScripter gave a nice workaround solution for the problem, but the runtime characteristics are not good because for each reconstructed word you have to loop through the whole dict.

I would say you chose the wrong dict design: To be efficient, lookup should be done in one step, so you should have the numbers as keys and the words as items.

Since your problem looks like a great computer science homework (I'll consider it for my students ;-) ), I'll just give you a sketch for the solution:

- use `word in my_dict.values() #(adapt for py2/py3)` to test whether the word is already in the dictionary.
- If no, `insert the next available index` as key and the word as value.
- you are done.
- For reconstructing the sentence, just

  - loop through your list of numbers
  - use the number as key in your dict and `print(my_dict[key])`
- Prepare exception handling for the case a key is not in the dict (which should not happen if you are controlling the whole process, but it's good practice).

This solution is much more efficient then your approach (and easier to implement).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use regular dicts and lists to store the data.  And use `json` or `pickle` to persist the data to disk.

```
import pickle

s = 'hi hello hi bye'
words = s.split()
d = {}
for word in word:
    if word not in d:
        d[word] = len(d)

data = [d[word] for word in words]

with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump({'lookup': d, 'data': data}, f)
```

Then read it back in

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    dic = pickle.load(f)
    d = d['lookup']
reverse_d = {v: k for k, v in d.iteritems()}
data = d['data']
words = [reverse_d[index] for index in data]
line = ' '.join(words)
print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know exactly how you have your keymap created the best I could do is guess. Here I have created 2 functions than can be used to write a string to a txt file based on a keymap and read a txt file and return a string based on a keymap. I hope this works for you or at least gives you a solid understanding on the process! Good Luck!

```
import os

def pack(out_file, string, conversion_map):
    out_string = ''
    for word in string.split(' '):
        for key,value in conversion_map.iteritems():
            if word.lower() == value.lower():
                out_string += str(key)+' '
                break
        else:
            out_string += word+' '

    with open(out_file, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(out_string)

    return out_string.rstrip()

def unpack(in_file, conversion_map, on_lookup_error=None):
    if not os.path.exists(in_file):
        return

    in_file = ''.join(open(in_file, 'rb').readlines())
    out_string = ''
    for word in in_file.split(' '):
        for key, value in conversion_map.iteritems():
            if word.lower() == str(key).lower():
                out_string += str(value)+' '
                break
        else:
            if on_lookup_error:
                on_lookup_error()
            else:
                out_string += str(word)+' '
    return out_string.rstrip()

def fail_on_lookup():
    print 'We failed to find all words in our key map.'
    raise Exception

string = 'Hello, my first name is thelazyscripter'
word_to_int_map = {0:'first',
                   1:'name',
                   2:'is',
                   3:'TheLazyScripter',
                   4:'my'}

d =  pack('data', string, word_to_int_map) #pack and write the data based on the conversion map

print d #the data that was written to the file
print unpack('data', word_to_int_map) #here we unpack the data from the file
print unpack('data', word_to_int_map, fail_on_lookup)
```